# Как добавить Placemark с текстом в Yandex MapKit на Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, yandexmapkit

Нужно нечто подобное, как это реализуется в JavaScript API для сайтов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При добавлении метки таким образом:

```
mapview.map.mapObjects.addPlacemark(Point(52.207970, 104.063277))
```

Создается обычная точка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В документации не нашел ни слова об этом. В примерах видел лишь подсовывание текста в TextView через ViewProvider, но не более.

Существует ли какой-либо штатный вариант создать нормальную метку с текстом через API? Если нет, то к какой альтернативе можно прибегнуть, чтобы создать что-то подобное?

Comment: Используйте [addPlacemark (@NonNull Point point, @NonNull ImageProvider image)](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/3.x/concepts/android/mapkit/ref/com/yandex/mapkit/map/MapObjectCollection-docpage/#method_detail__method_addPlacemark___NonNullPoint___NonNullImageProvider)

Comment: Вторым параметром передаете [ImageProvider](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/mapkit/doc/3.x/concepts/android/runtime/ref/com/yandex/runtime/image/ImageProvider-docpage/)

Comment: @zakiroof если во втором параметре я передам ImageProvider, то буду иметь только иконку. Если же во ViewProvider с TextView - то только текст, что указано в вопросе. Мне нужно и текст, и иконку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете нарисовать свой bitmap с помощью canvas, поместив на него нужный текст:

```
public Bitmap drawSimpleBitmap(String number) {
    int picSize = {нужный вам размер изображения};
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(picSize, picSize, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    // отрисовка плейсмарка
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.Green);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawCircle(picSize / 2, picSize / 2, picSize / 2, paint);
    // отрисовка текста
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setTextSize({Нужный размер текста});
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    canvas.drawText(number, picSize / 2,
            picSize / 2 - ((paint.descent() + paint.ascent()) / 2), paint);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Или использовать готовый битмап, например, из ресурсов (отресайзить если надо) и рисовать поверх него:

```
Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.your_icon_name);
// создаем mutable копию, чтобы можно было рисовать поверх
Bitmap bitmap = source.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
// инициализируем канвас
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
// рисуем текст на канвасе аналогично примеру выше
```

А затем отрисовать с помощью

```
addPlacemark(getPoint(),
                        ImageProvider.fromBitmap(drawSimpleBitmap(number))
```