# Как правильно использовать PlacemarkMapObject.SetText в yandex mapkit

Tags: java, android, yandexmapkit

мне нужно подписать метки на карте как в оригинале, в документации нашёл setText, но у меня текст не появляется https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/android-ref/lite/com/yandex/mapkit/map/TextStyle.html

```
PlacemarkMapObject placemark = mapObjects.addPlacemark(placeObject.point,imageProvider,new IconStyle());

        TextStyle textStyle = new TextStyle();

        textStyle.setSize(45);
        textStyle.setOffsetFromIcon(true);
        textStyle.setPlacement(TextStyle.Placement.BOTTOM);

        placemark.setText("text", textStyle);
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, использован пример с готовым изображением из этого ответа: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1182322/386299 . А размер использованного изображения действительно позволяет отрисовать поверх три длинных строки? Может просто не хватает места на нём?

Comment: Я не могу увеличить размер изображения, так как мне надо обрабатывать нажатия на метку, но тогда размеры меток станут слишком большие и могут налезать друг на друга.

Comment: Но если увеличить, текст помещается? Причину корректно определили хоть? Если да, может попробовать уточнить в поддержке Яндекса? Может они какой другой вариант многострочные подписи как реализовать предложат, если ваш не подходит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы указанный стиль применился к тексту нужно его передать вторым параметром в setText.

```
placemarkMapObject.setText("Test", testStyle);
```

И в качестве цвета желательно указывать не прозрачный цвет. textStyle.setColor(0) выставит все компоненты цвета в 0 включая альфа-канал.

```
textStyle.setColor(Color.BLACK)
```

Так же можно просто не указывать цвета и размер, тогда возьмутся дефолтные значения.

Text font size in units. default: 8
Text color. default: black
Outline color. default: white

Источник
https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-android-demo/issues/286

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)